# Javascript appear(); repeats one single fetch many times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im new to jquery, ajax and all that is to javascript

I created an **update without reload** with ajax, red tutorial in internet...so 
problem is that appear(); just posting and posting this one single value from fetch.php...
"spams" index.php like some kind of infinity value :D .
I need this to display it only once. I tried using class instead of id, but result is the same.

here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}

function updates() {
     $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.result, function(){
        $("div#"+this['cell_id']+"").append(this['result']);

       });
 });
}
```

but why, if i reload page (normally f5) then everything disapears?

Comment: probably because your `fetch.php` is returning the item every time, you should set it up to return only new data

Comment: replace `.append(this['result']);` with `.html(this['result']);`

Comment: @Oliboy50 that may solve it but it's not the best approach IMHO

Comment: @koala_dev i agree, but it's the easiest way i guess

Comment: yes it works! thanks a lot. but what is the problem @koala_dev

Comment: @user2784722 as I said, I would set up my data source to return only new items so the DOM is updated only when it needs to, I'm not sure if constantly updating the div could somehow affect user interaction with the content